# Clean uninstall of all .NET frameworks 1.1-3.5 on Windows XP

Tags: .net, uninstall

I've found information on uninstalling most of the .NET Frameworks using Msizap but having trouble uninstalling .NET 3.5 Framework. Some DLLs got corrupted from a recent virus attack and I'm having trouble running some of my .NET 1.1 applications that make use of the entire .NET library. Creating and running a test .NET 1.1 application of just a messagebox seems to work just fine but beyond that it's hosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the dot net clean up tool.  I had to use it once and it worked very well.

Tool

http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog_Tools/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip

User Guide

http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/pages/8904493.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your antivirus software can't clean it then the recommended solution is a clean ***re***-install of *everything* rather than trying to find and fix individual parts. You never know where things may be hiding.

Comment: The virus is remedied already. The issue is repairing the .NET dlls that were left corrupted by the virus. We've given the unit a clean bill of health. I agree that a full reinstall would be best but we're up against some really hard deadlines and this system cannot go down right now. It's responsible for making too many million dollar transactions right now. How I could slap the guy that put a dirty disc in the CD tray right now.

Comment: You have more problems that viruses if a single Windows XP machine is mission critical for your business.

Comment: Million dollar transactions by a machine worth a couple hundred? Get real. This is exactly why you are in this mess.